# PHP - How to parse an external URL to find an unknown get parameter

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a script that can find and identify an Amazon Affiliate ID from the URL.

I know the Affiliate ID appears after the parameter "&tag=" but it's location in the URL is not always consistent.  Sometimes it's in the middle:

```
http://www.amazon.com/gp/goldbox?&tag=adamcarolla09-20&camp=217705&creative=406565&linkCode=ur1&adid=1S1WPEJM5M1Y1RRW2875&
```

Sometimes it's at the end:

```
http://www.amazon.com/?_encoding=UTF8&camp=1789&creative=9325&linkCode=ur2&tag=schlockmercenary
```

How can I write a script that goes through the URL and returns just the tag, regardless of it's position in the string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [PHP parse str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php):

```
<?php
    // ...
    parse_str($url, $output);
    echo $output['tag'];
?>
```

Comment: To anybody this might help: **always remember to pass a second parameter to `parse_str()` or you'll silently inject a bunch of variables into the local scope.** This is bad for obvious reasons

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
$tag = strstr($url, "tag=");
$tag = substr($tag, 4, strlen($tag) -4 -strlen(strstr($tag, "&")));
$tag = urldecode($tag);
```

Comment: This doesn't parse eventual special URL characters